# Django + Caddy = CSRF protection issues

Tags: python, django, docker, reverse-proxy, caddy

I deployed a Django 4 app with Daphne (ASGI) in a docker container. I use Caddy as a reverse proxy in front. It works, except I can't fill in any form because the CSRF protection kicks in. So no admin login, for example.

I can currently access the admin interface in two ways:

1. Directly through docker, via a SSH tunelled port
2. Through Caddy, which is then forwarding to the Docker container.

Option 1 works. I can log into the admin interface just as if I was running the development server locally. All is working as expected.

However, option 2 (caddy reverse proxy) doesn't work. I can access Django and load pages, but any form submission will be blocked because the CSRF protection kicks in.

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
    Origin checking failed - https://<mydomain.com> does not match any trusted origins.
```

My Caddyfile contains this:

```
<mydomain.com> {
       reverse_proxy localhost:8088
}
```

localhost:8088 is the port exposed by my docker container.

In an effort to eliminate potential issues, I've set the following to false in my config file:

- `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` (causes a redirect loop, probably related to the reverse proxying)
- `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` (I'd rather have it set to True, but I don't know at this point)
- `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` (same remark)

The only Django-Caddy examples I could find online are outdated and refer to older versions of Caddy and/or Django. Django is deployed on ASGI with Daphne.

I've seens posts suggesting to change `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`, but it doesn't seem right that I would have to add a host that is already in the ALLOWED_HOSTS list. That also wouldn't explain why it works directly on the docker container, unless localhost is a special case for CSRF.

Versions:

- Caddy: 2.5.1
- Django: 4.0.5
- Daphne: 3.0.2
- Python: 3.10.5

Any idea what goes wrong, and how I should go about debugging such issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found out what was happening.

I first wanted to know the exact HTTP request that was sent from caddy to django:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -A -n port 8088
```

This confirmed that:

- the `Origin` and `Referer` headers were set properly
- the `csrftoken` cookie was sent properly

Once that was known, I could dig in the code from django. Specifically, [this function in the CSRF middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/db588d4f0edde5095f8975be1da4e693268b86b3/django/middleware/csrf.py#L277).

In conclusion:

1. Caddy forwards the http request to django unencrypted (so HTTP-non-S between caddy and django).
2. Django considers that request non-secure
3. The CSRF protection expects the `Origin` header sent by the browser to be `http://` because the request is not secure. In my case, it is `https://` because my browser is talking to Caddy over https
4. Because the `Origin` header does not match what the CSRF middleware expects, the request is rejected

It's actually a simple fix.

Since we know that [Caddy will always ignore](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#defaults) `X-Forwarded-Proto` from the browser and sets it itself, we can add [SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header) to the `settings.py` in django:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

And voilà!

Now I can also set these to true:

- SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT
- SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE
- CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE

**EDIT**
Here's the Caddyfile, as per requested:

```
service.mywebsite.com {
        reverse_proxy localhost:8088
}
```

Comment: Could you please give the example of your Caddyfile settings for the Origin and Referrer? Just setting SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER didn't work for me and I think it has something to do with Caddy.

Comment: @HermanMartinus Sure, but there's nothing special in it. I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: the solution for me was not Caddy side, but setting `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` since there is a discrepancy between the Origin and Referrer otherwise, causing Django to throw an insecure error.